# When entering some blocks it gives react-dom.min.js on console "Switching useSelect from mapping to mapping"

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

Here is the case, I am using greenshift WP and some of the block elements, when i am trying to put them on page, it causes invalid block error which generate console msgs like this

**This block has encountered an error and cannot be previewed.**

In the browser console - in edge/chrome error text:

```
   react-dom.min.js:10 Error: Switching useSelect from mapping to mapping is not allowed
    at Je (data.min.js:9:2838)
    at Nd (block-editor.min.js:26:196324)
    at edit (index.js:1:268694)
    at wt (react-dom.min.js:10:47637)
    at vr (react-dom.min.js:10:56452)
    at js (react-dom.min.js:10:121453)
    at wl (react-dom.min.js:10:88659)
    at bl (react-dom.min.js:10:88587)
    at yl (react-dom.min.js:10:88450)
    at il (react-dom.min.js:10:85274)
   ar @ react-dom.min.js:10
```

location of the reach-dom.min.js is `https://www.example.com/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.min.js`

Additionally, it has another error:
`Failed to load resource: https://www.example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/attributes?per_page=100&_locale=user the server responded with a status of 404 ()` - where it seems like it is woocommerce related but I do not have woocommerce installed.